# The meaning of $\overset{v}{=}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation

In the Corollaire I.9.11. of [SGA I](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203.pdf), the author uses the symbol $\overset{v}{=}$, which I have never seen before. I asked some people if they know what this means but none of them knew. Does anyone know the meaning of this symbol?

[image: SGA I, Exposé I, Corollaire 9.11.]

Comment: What is SGA I ????

Comment: If a textbook, try with the list of symbols.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Séminaire de Géométrie Algébrique

Comment: Basic rule: if it is not defined and used only one, probably is a typo.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't have a copy at hand now.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If it were almost any other obscure acronym, I would be upset with the OP. But SGA is one of the most famous...graduate level mathematics texts/notes of all time, and a search for `SGA math` or a skim of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGA reveals what it is. I basically don't know anything about algebraic geometry, but feel like SGA is probably fair to reference on MathOverflow without comment. Admittedly, the OP could have added a tag for the field of math, which might be relevant, both for giving you context for SGA, and for the symbol in question (could v stand for variété?)

Comment: @MarkS. This is not MathOverflow, this is math.stackexchange.

Comment: I think this just means $:=$ a symbol you use when you want to define something by an equality in the middle of the text.

Comment: I agree with @ali. Although my French is poor and I'm approximating some things, the text seems to be saying "for a certain irreducible component $U_i$ of $U$, define $X_i$ to be the closure (in $X$) of $U_i$, and then $X_i$ is an irreducible component of $X$."

Comment: I also agree with ali and Tabes Bridges, but then what does "v" mean?